# can i switch focus on windows or tabs based on user input using javascript or any other tech?

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs, window, onfocus

1. I have a webpage that shows a list of results.
2. I click on one of the result to view a product. It opens up a new window/tab.
3. Now I have 2 windows/tabs from the same website, but 1 showing result page and the other a product page.
4. Inside the product page, I have a link that says "Back To List"
5. If I press on it, I can go back to the same list of results.
6. So now I have two windows/tabs showing the same list of results.

The new behavior I am interested to know if it works is:

a) if I click on Back To List in the product page, can I switch focus to the original window/tab that shows the list of results, rather than what I have described in 5 & 6?

b) if answer to a is yes, can I do for multiple product windows? ie if I repeat step 2 multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar this:

```
var BackToList = function() {
    window.opener.focus(); // this sets the focus on the window that opened your product
    window.close();  // and this closes the product window
};
```

Then your link should call the `BackToList` function..

If your link is a simple `a` tag AND it has an id, you go like this on your window `load` event:

```
document.getElementById("the id goes here").onclick = BackToList;
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my requirements. a) I do not wish to close the product page. b) if there are multiple windows or tabs opened, how does your javascript code focus on the window that showed the result list?

Comment: Okay I apologize. All I need to do is comment out the 2nd line in your function. I think this should work well. Thankyou.